# Unity error while loading image from Windows Phone gallery

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, load, gallery

I have developped a Windows Phone plugin for my Unity application which enable me to open the Windows Phone gallery in order to select an image and get its physic path.

I've used this path to load the image in the application with a WWW object but I get this error

"Error. Operation has failed with error 0x80070005: access is denied."

The path is correct because I display it.

Here is my test code to load the image with the path.

```
 IEnumerator loadImage()
 {
     this.guiText.text = filePath;
     WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
     yield return www;

     if(www.error == null)
     {
         GameObject texture = GameObject.Find("UNITY");
         if(texture != null)
         {
             texture.guiTexture.texture = www.texture;
         }
     }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable the permission for your application to give access to read files from the device.

Go to App Manifest file and check whether it is enabled or not, if not that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I manipulate Windows Phone (and plus from Unity) so I'm really new to it, I found the App.xaml but I've absolutely no idea how to add access, there is nothing about it in it. Can you explain me how it works ?

Comment: Then open PackageAppManifest file from your Solution Explorer and you will find four tabs, among them chose Capabilities and tick MEdia Photo Option and save.

Comment: I haven't done that before, I've just ticked the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO option in the Capabilities tab from the WMAAppManifest.xml but I still have the same error, I don't know what else could I do ...

Comment: Sorry No information on WWW . Try to post the issue in MSDN communities.

Comment: WWW is an object that comes from Unity API, it enables you to load a picture from its physical path, it worked without problems with my Android plugin, I'm trying to do the same with Windows Phone